# Gulp production build terminated

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp, bower, yeoman

I am using angular 1.4.14, bower 1.8.0 and npm 3.6.0. I have used the following yeoman generator,https://github.com/dustinspecker/generator-ng-poly, to setup my project. I have full fledged web-ui ready in development mode when i run "gulp" cmd. But when i'm trying to generate production build by 'gulp --stage prod', which terminates without any log before minifying the templates. Find below the last logs generated,

```
[22:29:06] ESLint found no problems in 1 file
[22:29:06] Finished 'markup' after 2.29 s
[22:29:06] Starting 'scripts'...
[22:29:13] gulp-imagemin: Minified 26 images (saved 109.57 kB - 12.9%)
[22:29:13] Finished 'scripts' after 6.69 s
[22:29:13] Finished 'images' after 8.73 s
user@user:frontend$
```

I have checked all the console logs prior to this, there isn't any error or fatal error message displayed. The same code works in development mode.

How do I know whats failing the production build?